Polars: Rolling groups with starting indices set by a different column
I’m working on a dataset with Polars (Python), and I’m stumped on a “rolling” grouping operation. The data looks like this:



updated_at
last_trade_ts
ask_price
ask_qty
bid_price
bid_qty




2023-12-20 15:30:54 CET
2023-12-20 15:30:42 CET
114.2
1.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:31:38 CET
2023-12-20 15:30:42 CET
112.0
15.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:31:44 CET
2023-12-20 15:30:42 CET
112.0
13.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:31:58 CET
2023-12-20 15:31:56 CET
112.0
1.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:33:14 CET
2023-12-20 15:31:56 CET
112.0
1.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:33:27 CET
2023-12-20 15:31:56 CET
112.0
1.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:33:36 CET
2023-12-20 15:31:56 CET
112.0
1.2
109.49
0.1


2023-12-20 15:33:47 CET
2023-12-20 15:31:56 CET
112.0
1.2
109.49
0.1



What I want to do is aggregate data in 5-minute windows with starting times set by the updated_at column, but only when there are new values in the last_trade_ts column.
For example, in the fragment above, I want to have
updated_at BETWEEN '2023-12-20 15:30:54' AND '2023-12-20 15:35:54'

for the first group, and
updated_at BETWEEN '2023-12-20 15:31:58' AND '2023-12-20 15:36:58'

for the second.
Of course, one possible solution would be to apply the .rolling() method on updated_at and then select only the first row from a subsequent grouping by last_trade_ts. However, the dataset is quite large, and this approach involves a lot of unnecessary calculations.
Is there a way to perform something similar to what .rolling() does, but with a subset of starting indices?
P.S. I’m open to solutions using other tools, if needed. If someone has a solution in R, I can also consider migrating to that.

Can you create a new start time first? start = pl.col("updated_at").first().over(pl.col("last_trade_ts").rle_id()) (assuming I am understanding the problem correctly)

Not an answer per se, but from what I see, the goal is kind of using DataFrame.group_by_dynamic, using every over last_trade_ts while using period over updated_at.

@jqurious This suffers from the same problem as the solution I hinted at, .rolling() would create a 5-minute rolling window starting from every value of start, not only once per rle_id() as I would like

@RomanPekar that's the idea yes, but unfortunately .group_by_dynamic() only takes a single index_column and works with fixed every/period timedeltas

I cannot come up with solution which would use .group_by_dynamic()  cause you can only use single column for both every and period parameters.
One possible way of doing it would be more classical pre-window functions sql-like style, with DataFrame.join().
So, first we create a separate DataFrame which gives us list of start moments of desired groups. To do that, we would use Expr.rle_id(), the index column which would increase by 1 every time last_trade_ts changes:
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col("last_trade_ts").rle_id().alias('i'))
)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┬─────┐
│ updated_at          ┆ last_trade_ts       ┆ ask_price ┆ i   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ --- │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64       ┆ u32 │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═════╡
│ 2023-12-20 15:30:54 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:30:42 ┆ 114.2     ┆ 0   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:38 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:30:42 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 0   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:44 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:30:42 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 0   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:58 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:31:56 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 1   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:33:14 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:31:56 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 1   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:33:27 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:31:56 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 1   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:33:36 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:31:56 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 1   │
│ 2023-12-20 15:33:47 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:31:56 ┆ 112.0     ┆ 1   │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┴─────┘

now, we don't need this column, we only want to use it as a grouping index:
df_groups = (
    df  
    .group_by(pl.col("last_trade_ts").rle_id())
    .agg(pl.col("updated_at").first())
    .drop("last_trade_ts")
)

┌─────────────────────┐
│ updated_at          │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:58 │
│ 2023-12-20 15:30:54 │
└─────────────────────┘

Alternatively, you can use DataFrame.unique():
df_groups = (
    df
    .unique("last_trade_ts",keep="first")
    .select("updated_at")
)

┌─────────────────────┐
│ updated_at          │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 15:30:54 │
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:58 │
└─────────────────────┘

Now what we want to do is to join df_groups to df on condition df.updated_at between df_groups.updated_at and df_groups.updated_at + 5 minutes.
Unfortunately, polars is not great on inequality joins, so you can either use cross join and .filter() afterwards:
(    
    df_groups
    .join(df, how="cross")
    .filter(
        pl.col("updated_at_right") >= pl.col("updated_at"),
        pl.col("updated_at_right") <= pl.col("updated_at") + pl.duration(minutes=5)
    )
    .group_by("updated_at")
    .agg(pl.col("updated_at_right").max())
)

┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ updated_at          ┆ updated_at_right    │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:58 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:33:47 │
│ 2023-12-20 15:30:54 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:33:47 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

Alternatively, you can also use duckdb and use sql to get the results:
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        df_groups.updated_at as start,
        max(df.updated_at) as end
    from df_groups
        inner join df on
            df.updated_at >= df_groups.updated_at and
            df.updated_at <= df_groups.updated_at + interval 5 minutes
    group by
        df_groups.updated_at
""").pl()

┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ start               ┆ end                 │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 15:31:58 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:33:47 │
│ 2023-12-20 15:30:54 ┆ 2023-12-20 15:33:47 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘


Thank you so much!! The first solution becomes a bit too memory-heavy, but the inequality join with duckdb works perfectly :)

as much as I like polars I found that there's a certain subset of tasks which just works better with sql
